# 2 gradle projects using a local gradle dependancy in IntelliJ, but one cannot call models in the dependancy

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, swagger

I have a Gradle project called **clevergift-core** with all my API service files. In the project I have 2 swagger files that define models. I use [Gradle Swagger Generator Plugin](https://github.com/int128/gradle-swagger-generator-plugin/blob/master/README.md) to generate models from these 2 files. The code in build.gradle to generate these models is:

```
swaggerSources {
    clevergift {
        inputFile = file('src/main/resources/models.yaml')
        code {
            language = 'java'
            configFile = file('config.json')
            components = ['models']
        }
    }
    businesscard {
        inputFile = file('src/main/resources/businesscardmodels.yaml')
        code {
            language = 'java'
            configFile = file('businesscardsconfig.json')
            components = ['models']
        }
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn swaggerSources.clevergift.code , swaggerSources.businesscard.code
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs "${swaggerSources.clevergift.code.outputDir}/src/main/java", "${swaggerSources.businesscard.code.outputDir}/src/main/java"
sourceSets
```

In the project I run: `./gradlew generateSwaggerCode`

and this generates the models in `clevergift-core/build/swagger-code-businesscard/` and `clevergift-core/build/swagger-code-clevergift/`. Heres what it looks like in IntelliJ:

[image]

The business card models have the package `com.clevercards.businesscardmodels` and the clevergift models have the package `com.clevergift.models`.

I also have 2 other Gradle projects - `clevergift-api` and `clevercards-business-api`. These import clevergift-core as a dependancy:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.cb:clevergift-core:3.20.853-SNAPSHOT'
    ...
```

In IntelliJ I see this for clevergift-api
[image]

and this for clevercards-business-api:
[image]

In `clevergift-api` I can import models from `com.clevergift.models` and from `com.clevercards.businesscardmodels`.

However in `clevercards-business-api` I can only import models from `com.clevergift.models`, but not `com.clevercards.businesscardmodels`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there some setting I have set for `clevergift-api` but not for `clevercards-business-api` in IntelliJ?

Comment: Why do you have a snapshot dependency instead of a project dependency, if they live in the same multi-project? Have you tried `implementation(project("clevergift-core"))` instead of `compile 'com.cb:clevergift-core:3.20.853-SNAPSHOT'`. Which Gradle version and swagger-generator are you using. Can you share a [Build Scan](https://scans.gradle.com/)?

Comment: turned out invalidating the cache in Intellij fixed it